# Image anti-aliasing after animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, animation, antialiasing

I've developed a simple click game where you click an image and it gets replaced by another image. The first image is faded out and the next image is faded in using jQuery/animate/toggle.

After each animation the anti-aliasing on all images is lost for a second. It then reapplies anti-aliasing to all images.

Is it possible to force anti-aliasing constantly or force it to refresh faster so there's no time where images are not anti-aliased?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, in an embedded WebKit on Mac OS X, using this (non-standard) CSS works to preserve the antialiasing of images during CSS animations:

```
img {
   image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
}
```

This may not work for other browsers, of course. [The mozilla.org site claims that this behave as an alias of 'auto'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering) but it definitely changes the behaviour in WebKit.